# Storing prompts and their set of options using SQLAlchemy ORM in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, enums, orm, fastapi

I'm working on a FastAPI application and I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM. I've to store the following data in the database.

```
Prompt #1: ""
Options for prompt #1: ["", "", ..., ""]

Prompt #2: ""
Options for prompt #2: ["", "", ..., ""]

...
```

Every prompt will have a set of options and a user can only select from those options. Every user will select an option for every prompt and I've to store this information in the database. Right now, I've the following setup.

```py
class Base():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class User(Base):
    # fields...

    prompt_answers = relationship("PromptAnswer", back_populates="user")

class Prompt(Base):
    __tablename__ = "prompts"

    prompt = Column(String, nullable=False)

    prompt_answers = relationship("PromptAnswer", back_populates="prompt")

class PromptAnswer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "prompts_answers"

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    prompt_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("prompts.id"))
    answer = Column(String, nullable=False)

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="prompt_answers")
    prompt = relationship("Prompt", back_populates="prompt_answers")
```

Right now I'm thinking of manually adding all the prompts to the database and storing options for every prompt in a JSON file locally and reading it as and when needed. All the validation will be performed by the controllers before saving this information to the database. But I'm not sure if it's the best way to go. I know we can use `Enum` as a datatype for columns. So, is there a way to achieve this using Enums and if so, then how should I perform validation?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just store your options for each prompt in a PromptOption class? A one-to-many relationship between Prompt and PromptOption will do the job. And what kind of validation are you referring to?

Comment: validation, as in, if the user has selected option only from the allowed options.